# Restrict IAM policy for specific VPCs for any actions on ec2 using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, identity-management

**Motivation**: **TLDR** *I want to grant permissions to some aws IAM role to be able to access ALL ec2 actions* ( such as instance create/delete/stop/tag/ip-assignment etc... ) *in specific VPCs*.

**For example**: User that implements this IAM role would be able to access `vpc_a` and `vpc_b` and create multiple machines of t3.xlarge and m5.large that contains some application on top of that. That user doesn't any have access to create any machines on `vpc_c` which is sensitive and restricted.

for that mission I created some special IAM policy:

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc_a" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["vpc_a"]
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc_b" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["vpc_b"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "restircted_vpc_iam_policy" {
  statement {
      actions   = ["ec2:*"]
      effect    = "Allow"
      resources = ["arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:subnet/*"]
        condition {
          test     = "ArnEquals"
          variable = "ec2:Vpc"
          values = [
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:vpc/${data.aws_vpc.vpc_a.id}",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:vpc/${data.aws_vpc.vpc_b.id}"
          ]
      }
      sid       = "vpcRestriction"
    }

    statement {
      actions   = ["ec2:*"]
      effect    = "Allow"
      resources = [
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:instance/*",
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:volume/*",
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:network-interface/*",
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:key-pair/*",
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:security-group/*",
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:image/*",
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:elastic-ip/*",
           "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:ipv4pool-ec2/*"
      ] 
      sid       = "ec2MachineCreationAdditionalResources"
    }
  }
```

I used some aws reference with sort of a similar use case ( [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-policy-examples.html#subnet-ami-example-iam) ), However that user is not authorized to perform any of the following actions and this policy fails. Any idea what is the missing piece?

Comment: Can you list the actions that failed?

Comment: `ec2:runInstance` for example.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Authorization error for this IAM role

Comment: You can use [DecodeAuthorizationMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_DecodeAuthorizationMessage.html) to get additional information.

Comment: `allowed:false`,
`explicitDeny:false`,
`action:ec2:RunInstances`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247002/discussion-between-avivamg-and-jellycsc).

Comment: might be some problem get some private amazon image that was built on packer? although I gave general permissions to images `"arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789:image/*"` - private images should not have "owner" digits on the iam? seeing some error that mentioned `"arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1::image/<some-id>"` but not sure it's related.